# Outlook VML background doest show

Tags: html, email, ms-office, html-email

Using the example from 'bulletproof backgrounds' doesnt work for me on outlook clients.
Is there any way to do this for outlook or is it just a straight up no?

Heres my code for reference. (some things i have tried)

```
   <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <v:background fillcolor="red">
    <v:fill type="gradient"/>
    
    good day 
    </v:background>
 <![endif]-->


  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="t">
    <v:fill type="tile" src="https://i.imgur.com/YJOX1PC.png" color="#7bceeb"/>
  </v:background>
  <![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is missing the `xmlns:v` attribute, as well as the `fill="t"`. Here’s a full working example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>VML Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<!--[if mso]>
<v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" fillcolor="red">
<v:fill type="gradient"/>
</v:background>
<![endif]-->
<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Culpa, saepe?</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Your second example works right out of the box for me (as, I presume, it comes from [backgrounds.cm](https://www.backgrounds.cm)). Please note though that VML is only supported on the Outlooks on Windows. And `<v:background>` is not supported in dark mode.

Comment: Weird... This doesnt work on my outlook and im on windows

Comment: Can you be more specific and give your exact Outlook version number? Also, what are you using to send your email?